# Stub native ECMAScript modules

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to stub or rewire imports of native ECMAScript modules?
All solution I found uses @std/esm or a transpiler.

For example: I would like to replace the 'nedb-promise with a stub

```
import Datastore from 'nedb-promise'
```

Comment: If you are at the point where you need to stub modules it may be a good time to rewrite your current module to accept such dependencies via injection instead of direct import.

Comment: Is for a legacy application. This app uses rewire for unit test / integration tests.